# onDestroy is calling When phone screen Off

Tags: android, android-service

i created a **sip call**. When phone screen is **turned on** and if i receive any incoming call, everthing is OK. I mean that onStart() is called and **onDestroy() is not called**. So i am able answer the call.
But When phone **screen is off** and an incoming call is received. i see that onStart() is called and **onDestroy() is also being called**. I see that android process automatically kills this activity.

This problem is not in android 2.3 version. i saw this in the latest version.

Any Solutions? my onDestroy() method should not be called. it should be called only when i come out of the activity.

Comment: Do you start another activity or do you move away from you activity in your onCreate() /onStart() before onDestroy() is being called?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the problem occurs when using screen "Landscape" only, because the screen changes to "portrait" internally.

To prevent this, call `onDestroy()` in case screen goes ON or OFF.

1. add to `AndroidManifest.xml` File with `"orientation|screenSize"` attribute.
2. add `onConfigurationChanged()` method to your activity

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
   …
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

And add to your activity:

```
…
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: just came across this, the part in the activity seems superfluous. It would do the same without overriding it

Answer (score 0):

You can go check in your developer options(On your latest version device), if you have enabled the 'Don't keep Activities' option. You can disable it. This could be one reason why onDestroy() is being called only on your latest version device.

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy method will call i your app is get force close or.. app is closed.. may be your app get closed by instance..   on onStop, onDestroy  will call wen you press back button,. onDestroy wont call wen you press home button

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your screen orientation as ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED or ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR in onCreateEngineOptions()?

I found that onDestroy would be called when using ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED. But if I use ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, onDestroy is not called when turning screen off.

I'm still not clear about the reasons behind this problem, but I think this is a clue to solve it.